# Rail 3 - Passenger path Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu, passenger

My application returns and error on any controller or model that requires a file.
typically I would require a file as shown below.

```
require '/lib/position_mover'
```

I played around with it a little bit and it seems to work if I specify a path from the top directory of my server show below.

```
require '/srv/www/testapp/lib/position_mover'
```

I want to use the relative path for many reasons. Can someone give me direction on this?

**Server config:**

- Apache 2
- Ubuntu 10.10
- rails 3.0.3
- ruby 1.9.2p0
- mysql

**Virtual host:**

```
<VirtualHost 173.255.238.220>
    ServerName test.targesoft.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/testapp/public/
    <Directory /srv/www/testapp/public/>
        PassengerAppRoot /srv/www/testapp/
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're requiring a file inside the `lib` directory of a Rails app, that's not necessary. Rails requires everything in there by default.

Comment: Sadly not in Rails 3 any more, you need to require things manually now.

Comment: Or you could add them to the autoload_path setting and when their constants are referenced they will be autoloaded

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to place this module in the `lib` directory and then add it to `config.autoload_paths` in your `config/application.rb` file (a setting which, by default, is commented out). When you reference this module in your code, Rails will automatically know to require the file in the `lib` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response! While plugins are the defacto for the lib folder, I'm actually calling in my own custom module here. I tried taking the require piece out from the top of the model, but unless I require it a the top of my file, I get an error for an undefined constant. There must be a way to set up passenger so that it looks in it's own directory by default.

```
module PositionMover

  def move_to_position(new_position)
    max_position = self.class.where(position_scope).count
    # ensure new_position is an integer in 1..max_position
      unless new_position.nil?
        new_position = [[1, new_position.to_i].max, max_position].min
      end

      if position == new_position # do nothing
        return true
      elsif position.nil? 
        increment_items(new_position, 1000000)
      elsif new_position.nil? 
        decrement_items(position+1, 1000000)
      elsif new_position < position 
        increment_items(new_position, position-1)
      elsif new_position > position
        decrement_items(position+1, new_position)
      end
      return update_attribute(:position, new_position)
    end


   def position_scope
    "1=1" 
   end

   def increment_items(first, last)
     items = self.class.where(["position >= ? and position <= ? AND #{position_scope}", first, last])
     items.each {|i| i.update_attribute(:position, i.position + 1)}
   end


   def decrement_items(first, last)
      items = self.class.where(["position >= ? and position <= ? AND #{position_scope}", first, last])
      items.each {|i| i.update_attribute(:position, i.position - 1)}
    end


end
```